# How to customize form (html) with fixed heading title and fixed footer with validation forms buttons?

Tags: css, django, forms

I develop Django apps and need to customize standard form for data entry that fit the structure in attached image bellow.

You can also see my current code that "do the job" but would like to know if it is the good way to do that or if there is better practices.

I have define css classes for my fixed heading-title, fixed footer-bottom and for my 2 buttons "Save" and "Cancel"

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-info fixed-top" style="padding-top: 50px;">...</nav>

<!-- content form for field data entry -->
<div class="box row-full" id="heading-title">
    <h3>Nouveau projet</h3>
</div>
<div class='container' style="margin-top:200px;margin-bottom:200px">
    <form id="projecteditform" method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button id="ajouter_projet" class="btn btn-info .fixed-save" type="submit"
            style="width: 100px; z-index:2">Valider</button>
        <a data-modal data-target="" class="btn btn-dark .fixed-cancel" href="{% url 'project:index_projet' %}"
            style="width: 100px; z-index:2">Annuler</a>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="box row-full" id="footer-buttons"></div>
<!-- end content form for field data entry -->

<footer class="page-footer font-small blue fixed-bottom" style="background-color:white; z-index:1">...</footer>
```

css

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 60px;
  color: white;
}

#heading-title {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  color:black;
  background: white;
}

#footer-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  background: white;
}
.row-full{
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
}

.fixed-save{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 80px;
}
```

Thanks for your advices[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In css recommended to use the id selector only for JavaScript.

   **Incorrect**:
   `#footer-buttons`
   `#heading-title`

   **Correct**:
   `.footer-buttons`
   `.heading-title`
2. It is not recommended to use inline styles in html.

   **Incorrect**:
   `style = "margin-top: 200px; margin-bottom: 200px"`

   **Correct**:
   `.someclass { top-margin: 200px;  bottom-margin: 200 pixels }`
3. It is recommended to use the `section` and `header` tags.

   http://htmlbook.ru/html/section

   http://htmlbook.ru/html/header
4. It is not recommended to use different quotation marks. The code looks dirty.
   Use `"`or `'`

   **Correct:**
   `class = "container"`
5. The dot is not needed here.

   `class = "btn btn-dark .fixed-cancel"`

Answer (score 0):

According to what I found [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) is one of the best ways to format django forms

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742261/django-what-is-the-best-way-to-format-forms)